# How to find all URLs in a string except the url inside image tag Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I receive a text editor string as response.

I need to find all the URL's in that string and showing the URLs inside a **Span** except the URL of **img** tag.

I have tried the following

```
ResetURLs: function (input) {
    var urlRegex = /(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$])/igm;
    return input.replace(urlRegex, function (url) {
        return '<span style="color:#0000EE" title=' + url + '>' + url + '</span>';
    })
}
```

This works, but it also modifies the URLs inside the **img** tag. Can anyone help me to modify this regex to omit all the URLs inside the **img** tags?

Thanks.

Comment: Down voting with reason may help me to correct my mistakes .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the [best trick ever](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick):

```
ResetURLs: function (input) {
    var urlRegex = /(<img\s[^>]*>)|(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$])/gi;
    return input.replace(urlRegex, function (url, img) { return img ? url : '<span style="color:#0000EE" title=' + url + '>' + url + '</span>'; })
}
```

**Details**

- `(<img\s[^>]*>)|` is prepended to the pattern as a capturing group with ID 1
- `m` flag is redundant, removed from the regex
- The second argument to `replace` is an anonymous function that takes `url` (the whole match) and `img` (the value in Group 1) arguments
- If `img` is present, if it matched, the `img` value is returned, else, the `span` with `url` is returned.

Comment: Can you help me to add span tag as like img tag to the regex @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @Zhu Replace `(<img\s[^>]*>)` with `(<img\s[^>]*>|<span(?:\s[^>]*)?>[\s\S]*?<\/span>)`. If it helped, please consider upvoting the answer.